# Twitter Integration API is not working

Tags: android, android-layout, twitter, twitter-oauth

First i have downloaded `twitter4j-3.0.3` and put its `.jar` files into `libs` folder of my eclipse app.After that i create an app on `https://dev.twitter.com/` and get all the credentials needed and gave callback url as `https://google.co.in`

Now my code is as follows

```
import twitter4j.Twitter;
import twitter4j.TwitterException;
import twitter4j.TwitterFactory;
import twitter4j.User;
import twitter4j.auth.AccessToken;
import twitter4j.auth.RequestToken;
import twitter4j.conf.Configuration;
import twitter4j.conf.ConfigurationBuilder;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class TwitterSampleActivity extends Activity  {

    private static final String CONSUMER_KEY = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    private static final String CONSUMER_SECRET = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    private static final String CALLBACK = "https://google.co.in";
    private  String OAuthToken;
    private  String OAuthSecret;
    private boolean isLogged;
    private static Twitter twitter;
    private static RequestToken requestToken;

    private Button loginButton;
    private Button logoutButton;
    private Button sendStatus;
    private EditText status;
    private TextView userName;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_twitter);

        loginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.twitter_log_in);
        logoutButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.twitter_log_out);
        sendStatus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.twitter_send);
        status = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.twitter_text);
        userName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.twitter_username);

        loginButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        userName.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        sendStatus.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        status.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        logoutButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        Uri uri = getIntent().getData();
        if(uri!=null && uri.toString().startsWith(CALLBACK)) {
            String verifier = uri.getQueryParameter("oauth_verifier");

            try {
                AccessToken token = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken(requestToken, verifier);

                OAuthToken = token.getToken();
                OAuthSecret = token.getTokenSecret();
                isLogged = true;

                loginButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                userName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                sendStatus.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                status.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                logoutButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                User user = twitter.showUser(token.getUserId());
                String username = user.getName();

                userName.setText("Logged as: " + username);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Login error: ", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    public void onLogInClicked(View v) {
        if(!isLogged) {
            ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
            builder.setOAuthConsumerKey(CONSUMER_KEY);
            builder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(CONSUMER_SECRET);
            Configuration config = builder.build();
            TwitterFactory factory = new TwitterFactory(config); 
            twitter = factory.getInstance();

            try {
                requestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken(CALLBACK);
                this.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
                        Uri.parse(requestToken.getAuthenticationURL())));
            } catch (TwitterException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Already logged", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    public void onLogOutclicked(View v) {
        OAuthToken = "";
        OAuthSecret = "";
        isLogged = false;

        loginButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        userName.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        userName.setText("");
        sendStatus.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        status.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        logoutButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }   


    public void onSendClicked(View v) {
        String text = status.getText().toString();
        if(text.length()>0) {
           new SendTwitterStatusUpdate(this, CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET,
               OAuthToken, OAuthSecret).execute(text);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Enter some text" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

}
```

and my `activity_twitter.xml` file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/twitter_log_in"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="twitter log in"
        android:onClick="onLogInClicked" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/twitter_username"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/twitter_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="text" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/twitter_send"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="twitter send"
        android:onClick="onSendClicked" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/twitter_log_out"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="twitter log_out"
        android:onClick="onLogOutClicked" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and `SendTwitterStatusUpdate.java` file is

```
import twitter4j.Twitter;
import twitter4j.TwitterFactory;
import twitter4j.auth.AccessToken;
import twitter4j.conf.ConfigurationBuilder;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SendTwitterStatusUpdate extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean>{

    private Context context;
    private String consumerKey;
    private String consumerSecret;
    private String accessToken;
    private String accessTokenSecret;

    public SendTwitterStatusUpdate(Context context, String consumerKey, String consumerSecret, String accessToken,String accessTokenSecret) {
        this.context=context;
        this.consumerKey=consumerKey;
        this.consumerSecret=consumerSecret;
        this.accessToken=accessToken;
        this.accessTokenSecret=accessTokenSecret;
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
        String status = params[0];

        if(status!=null) {
            try {
                ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
                builder.setOAuthConsumerKey(consumerKey);
                builder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(consumerSecret);

                AccessToken token = new AccessToken(accessToken, accessTokenSecret);
                Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory(builder.build()).getInstance(token);

                twitter.updateStatus(status);
                return true;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        if(result) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Status successfully updated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Status not updated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

Now when i run my application i got this window
[image: see the emulator which does not showing the full <code>twitter_activity.xml</code>]

and apart from that when i am clicking on that button `twitter log in` ...that button is not working..need help

}

can anyone tell me why i am getting null on `Uri uri = getIntent().getData();`...uri object value is null..thus this part is not executing

```
if(uri!=null && uri.toString().startsWith(CALLBACK)) {
            String verifier = uri.getQueryParameter("oauth_verifier");

            try {
                AccessToken token = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken(requestToken, verifier);

                OAuthToken = token.getToken();
                OAuthSecret = token.getTokenSecret();
                isLogged = true;

                loginButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                userName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                sendStatus.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                status.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                logoutButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                User user = twitter.showUser(token.getUserId());
                String username = user.getName();

                userName.setText("Logged as: " + username);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Login error: ", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
```

Comment: can anyone tell me why i am getting null on   Uri uri = getIntent().getData();

Comment: how you have solved your problem .I am getting the same error @Kingshuk Deb

Comment: dont work as android developer anymore and forgot how it was resolved..please google it

Comment: try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717740/twitter-oauth-integration?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Check out this Demo links , you will get idea how it works and then try to implement own

you can download both 
you have to just create your Twitter app.That is also explain by blogger.Follow them you will get two keys.

```
TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY="**********************";

TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET="********************";
```

Replace inside your activity and run your project.

[First Example](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-twitter-oauth-connect-tutorial/)

[Second Example](http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.in/2012/10/android-twitter-integration-in.html)

Enjoy.!!!

Comment: plz read the question first..i gave all the details there..i already have consumer_key and consumer_secret both..

Comment: after clicking that button it comes to `public void onLogInClicked()` and after `step over`(button) few lines it goes to catch section with twitterException

Comment: don't explain your flow here , that we know from code, post your error log cate

Comment: After `requestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken(CALLBACK);` line it goes to catch section

Comment: see in eclipse there are `logcat` open this and run your app, that will show you error and post that here. not image link and etc

Comment: sorry.. but can u plz tell me how to use OAuthToken,OAuthSecret..i am not using this in my code..

Comment: So, as i post my answer follow that link and do as they said you will get idea.

Comment: if you have other query then ask new question.and if this answer is helpful to you then accept it and share your upvote