# To connect my application with twitter

Tags: android

I have an example where i am getting an 401 error because the consumer is not correct or signature didn't match .How to put signature key here because in my working java example there is a signature key and i want to implement it.

```
public class TwitterApp {
private Twitter mTwitter;
private TwitterSession mSession;
private AccessToken mAccessToken;
private OAuthConsumer mHttpOauthConsumer;
private OAuthProvider mHttpOauthprovider;
private String mConsumerKey;
private String mSecretKey;
private ProgressDialog mProgressDlg;
private TwDialogListener mListener;
private Context context;

public static final String CALLBACK_URL = "twitterapp://connect";
private static final String TAG = "TwitterApp";

public TwitterApp(Context context, String consumerKey, String secretKey) {
    this.context    = context;

    mTwitter        = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
    mSession        = new TwitterSession(context);
    mProgressDlg    = new ProgressDialog(context);

    mProgressDlg.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    mConsumerKey    = consumerKey;
    mSecretKey      = secretKey;

    mHttpOauthConsumer = new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer(mConsumerKey, mSecretKey);
    mHttpOauthprovider = new CommonsHttpOAuthProvider("http://twitter.com/oauth/request_token",
                                                 "http://twitter.com/oauth/access_token",
                                                 "http://twitter.com/oauth/authorize");

    mAccessToken    = mSession.getAccessToken();

    configureToken();
}

public void setListener(TwDialogListener listener) {
    mListener = listener;
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private void configureToken() {
    if (mAccessToken != null) {
        mTwitter.setOAuthConsumer(mConsumerKey, mSecretKey);

        mTwitter.setOAuthAccessToken(mAccessToken);
    }
}

public boolean hasAccessToken() {
    return (mAccessToken == null) ? false : true;
}

public void resetAccessToken() {
    if (mAccessToken != null) {
        mSession.resetAccessToken();

        mAccessToken = null;
    }
}

public String getUsername() {
    return mSession.getUsername();
}

public void updateStatus(String status) throws Exception {
    try {
        mTwitter.updateStatus(status);
    } catch (TwitterException e) {
        throw e;
    }
}

public void authorize() {
    mProgressDlg.setMessage("Initializing ...");
    mProgressDlg.show();

    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            String authUrl = "";
            int what = 1;

            try {
                authUrl = mHttpOauthprovider.retrieveRequestToken(mHttpOauthConsumer, CALLBACK_URL);    

                what = 0;

                Log.d(TAG, "Request token url " + authUrl);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Failed to get request token");

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            mHandler.sendMessage(mHandler.obtainMessage(what, 1, 0, authUrl));
        }
    }.start();
}

public void processToken(String callbackUrl)  {
    mProgressDlg.setMessage("Finalizing ...");
    mProgressDlg.show();

    final String verifier = getVerifier(callbackUrl);

    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int what = 1;

            try {
                mHttpOauthprovider.retrieveAccessToken(mHttpOauthConsumer, verifier);

                mAccessToken = new AccessToken(mHttpOauthConsumer.getToken(), mHttpOauthConsumer.getTokenSecret());

                configureToken();

                User user = mTwitter.verifyCredentials();

                mSession.storeAccessToken(mAccessToken, user.getName());

                what = 0;
            } catch (Exception e){
                Log.d(TAG, "Error getting access token");

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            mHandler.sendMessage(mHandler.obtainMessage(what, 2, 0));
        }
    }.start();
}

private String getVerifier(String callbackUrl) {
    String verifier  = "";

    try {
        callbackUrl = callbackUrl.replace("twitterapp", "http");

        URL url         = new URL(callbackUrl);
        String query    = url.getQuery();

        String array[]  = query.split("&");

        for (String parameter : array) {
             String v[] = parameter.split("=");

             if (URLDecoder.decode(v[0]).equals(oauth.signpost.OAuth.OAUTH_VERIFIER)) {
                 verifier = URLDecoder.decode(v[1]);
                 break;
             }
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return verifier;
}

private void showLoginDialog(String url) {
    final TwDialogListener listener = new TwDialogListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(String value) {
            processToken(value);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(String value) {
            mListener.onError("Failed opening authorization page");
        }
    };

    new TwitterDialog(context, url, listener).show();
}

private Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        mProgressDlg.dismiss();

        if (msg.what == 1) {
            if (msg.arg1 == 1)
                mListener.onError("Error getting request token");
            else
                mListener.onError("Error getting access token");
        } else {
            if (msg.arg1 == 1)
                showLoginDialog((String) msg.obj);
            else
                mListener.onComplete("");
        }
    }
};

public interface TwDialogListener {
    public void onComplete(String value);       

    public void onError(String value);
}
```

}

i have an working example of java also where, i am getting the token easily but the thing is it uses DefaultOAuthConsumer and DefaultOAuthProvider but whenever i am trying to implement it in my example i am getting communication error, thats why i use CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer and CommonsHttpOAuthProvider.

here's the java working code

public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    OAuthConsumer consumer = new DefaultOAuthConsumer(
            "iIlNngv1KdV6XzNYkoLA",
            "exQ94pBpLXFcyttvLoxU2nrktThrlsj580zjYzmoM",
            SignatureMethod.HMAC_SHA1);

    OAuthProvider provider = new DefaultOAuthProvider(consumer,
            "http://twitter.com/oauth/request_token",
            "http://twitter.com/oauth/access_token",
            "http://twitter.com/oauth/authorize");

    System.out.println("Fetching request token from Twitter...");

    // we do not support callbacks, thus pass OOB
    String authUrl = provider.retrieveRequestToken(OAuth.OUT_OF_BAND);

    System.out.println("Request token: " + consumer.getToken());
    System.out.println("Token secret: " + consumer.getTokenSecret());

    System.out.println("Now visit:\n" + authUrl
            + "\n... and grant this app authorization");
    System.out.println("Enter the PIN code and hit ENTER when you're done:");

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String pin = br.readLine();

    System.out.println("Fetching access token from Twitter...");

    provider.retrieveAccessToken(pin);

    System.out.println("Access token: " + consumer.getToken());
    System.out.println("Token secret: " + consumer.getTokenSecret());

    URL url = new URL("http://twitter.com/statuses/mentions.xml");
    HttpURLConnection request = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    consumer.sign(request);

    System.out.println("Sending request to Twitter...");
    request.connect();

    System.out.println("Response: " + request.getResponseCode() + " "
            + request.getResponseMessage());
}
```

}

and i am also not aware for call back url string i am using it here..

Comment: I would like to suggest something here like please don't use DefaultOAuth* implementations on Android, Instead, use the CommonsHttpOAuth* classes, since they are meant to be used with Apache Commons HTTP (that's what Android uses for HTTP anyway). It's a bug in android, Android's java.net.HttpURLConnection that keeps it from working with some service providers. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CALLBACK_URL should match the

```
<intent-filter>
```

in your manifest.xml.

In your code snippets, have you declared and initialized the mHttpOathCosumer and provider?

Comment: no i didnt how could i, can you give me some example. I did some changes in it also like right now i am seeing the google site and they are saying that Do NOT use the DefaultOAuth* implementations on Android  Instead, use the CommonsHttpOAuth* its a bug in Android's java.net.HttpURLConnection so now i am using this and got the response but still got authorization failed due to consumer key was not correct or signature didn't match but my consumer key is correct. help me

Comment: Yeah. According to Android you should not use the DefaultOauth. These two topics might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1965568/oauth-instance-state-in-android and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357372/ioexception-received-authentication-challenge-is-null-apache-harmony-android

Comment: Yeah i already seen those links but still i not getting my ans. the fact is very similar to them yeah i am getting the same error 401 but still don't know how to solve it. :(

Comment: Can it will be a problem by CALLBACK_URL string because that is the only section left that i am not aware of it.

Comment: As Mathias said, you probably don't attach the OAuth verifying code to the request when you try to retrieve information.

Comment: Actually i am working on an application that our company already had on i-phone and they provide me the consumer key and secret key that they are using in their application and it work fine for them.

Comment: They didn't provide me any CALLBACK_URL String. So i am using the sample application CALLBACK_URL for my test, IS it correct? to use it.